# Hanging a left hinged door as a right hinged door

Tags: doors, exterior, steel

I purchased a steel door that has hinges on the left side, if you’re standing inside the home. The door opens into the house, can I simply install the door with the hinges on the right? This will put the inside out and the outside in?

Comment: Is this a prehung door with a threshold included? If so, the threshold will probably need some work. If it's just the door, you may or may not have bevel issues... these days, fewer and fewer doors seem to be beveled from the factory.

Comment: if you move the hinges to the other side, what about door handle and lock

Comment: That would also make it open to the outside, right?

Comment: Is the doorknob close to halfway between top and bottom? You could turn the door upside down.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot hang a left hand hinge door with the hinges on the right unless you are willing to have the door open out (not good for an entry door). And then yes, the exterior of the door would be inside and the interior of the door would be outside.

It being a steel door (rather than a wood door) you cannot simply chisel the proper hinge mortise and repair it so that it will opens in and have the hinges on the right.

Comment: and you need the frame to support opening out.  You could turn it upside down maybe, lol.

Comment: Disagree with your opinion that an exterior outswing door is 'not good'. I'll absolutely agree that it's not conventional, but some people want an outswing.

Comment: Exterior outswing is actually *required* for safety in commercial buildings. But what you don't want is *hinge pins* accessible on the outside.